# How to pass parameter from srcipts and get in cordovaInAppBrowser those parameters in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am trying to integrate payment gateway, my idea is to complete it from cordovaInAppBrowser. So here is my script file

Scripts.js

```
 $rootScope.paymentdata.salt="sdfg"
     $rootScope.paymentdata.key="sdfg";
     $rootScope.paymentdata.amount=checkout.grandtotal;
     $rootScope.paymentdata.productinfo=$rootScope.cartlist
     $rootScope.paymentdata.firstname=$rootScope.userinfo.name;
     $rootScope.paymentdata.email=$rootScope.userinfo.email
     $rootScope.paymentdata.phone=$rootScope.userinfo.contactno;
     $rootScope.paymentdata.surl="http://localhost:8100/#/success.php"
     $rootScope.paymentdata.furl="http://localhost:8100/#/failure.php"
     $rootScope.paymentdata.service_provider="payu_paisa"
     var string = $rootScope.paymentdata.key + '|' + $rootScope.paymentdata.txnid + '|' + $rootScope.paymentdata.amount + '|' + $rootScope.paymentdata.productinfo + '|' + $rootScope.paymentdata.firstname + '|' + $rootScope.paymentdata.email + '|||||||||||' + $rootScope.paymentdata.salt;
$rootScope.paymentdata.hash=$scope.SHA512(string)
```

I have installed plugin of Cordova InAppBrowser, and i am using it as follow:

```
var browserWindow = $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('payumoney.html', '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=yes,hardwareback=no');
```

With Javascript window as follows,

```
var browserWindow = window.open('payumoney.html', '_self', 'location=yes,hidden=yes,hardwareback=no');
```

Here payumoney.html is my html file from which i want to complete this process. In this payumoney.html i have the following input / parameter from which i can able to complete this payment.

payymoney.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="paymentdata.salt">..
```

so in this way i have all fields i am tring to send. But i am not able to get those parameters in that file.

So my question is, how to pass those parameters or get those parameters in that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between you app and the InAppBrowser page `payumoney.html` with the localStorage.

So in `Scripts.js` add this line :

```
localStorage.setItem('paymentdata', JSON.stringify($rootScope.payementdata));
```

And in `payumoney.html` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var paymentData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('paymentdata'));
alert(paymentData.salt):
</script>
```